# Can there be only one actor in a system use case diagram? PC can act as an actor or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, assistant

I am developing an Android application, a presentation assistant. in which smart phone and PC will be connecting through bluetooth. I am trying to write use cases, actors of application, I don't know if computer can be actor of a system or not? or how many actors my system will have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294287/how-to-determine-non-human-actors-of-a-use-case) would help.

Whatever, Actor in use case can be any person or object that will participate in some activity. So, a computer could be some sort of client who accepts phone's commands and performs action based on it.

**BUT**, in this case I would have User be only actor. He is the one who commands and all others are performing his commands. All others are the System, resources etc.